# Potential employer flew me out for interview, cancels return flight

Tags: interviewing, united-states, travel, expenses

A company I was interested in just flew me out for an interview.  It was on the other side of the country, so they paid for my flight and hotel.  Unfortunately, the interview went disastrously.  I blew every question, and I could tell that they didn't like me personally.

When I got to the airport for my return flight, I could not get my boarding pass.  The agent told me that the buyer cancelled my ticket for a partial refund.  Despite my persistence, they assured me that there wasn't a mistake.

I called the company to tell them there was a mix-up, but they just told me they decided they were "going in a different direction".  I told them it was fine that I didn't get the job, but I didn't have a flight home.  They repeated the same "going in a different direction" phrase and told me they couldn't help me.  After calling back 3 or 4 times, they told me to stop harassing them.

I'm completely broke due to poor financial decisions (that's a different story), so I can't afford a last-minute plane ticket.  It doesn't help that this is a small airport, so ticket prices are high.  So basically, I've been stuck at the airport for the past three days.  Yesterday, my credit card started being declined, so I've had to eat scraps from other customers.

Fortunately, I do have an existing (albeit awful) job when I get home.  And I finally got a friend of a friend to agree to pick me up and drive me to a Greyhound bus station in another town.  So while I'm sitting in the airport waiting for him, with a lot of time to think, I want to ask a few questions that have been spinning around my mind:

- Seriously, what the heck?  Is this normal for an employer to do?
- The more I think about, the more I'm thinking I must have said something offensive to somebody in an interview.  Is there any way to
  ask them what I said (so that I can avoid this mistake in the
  future)?

A specific legal question about *recourse against this employer* [has been asked on Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36259/if-a-company-agrees-to-pay-travel-cost-for-a-job-interview-is-the-promise-bindi).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88383/discussion-on-question-by-snah-potential-employer-flew-me-out-for-interview-can).

Comment: **Before you comment:** the case of fake CV ***has*** been brought up in previous comments, more than once. Please read existing answers and add your own if you feel that's gonna be of value; otherwise go to the chat room for more extended discussions.

Comment: @Marc.2377 -- So what was the OP's response to "the case of fake CV has been brought up in previous comments"? If we ask, shouldn't it be addressed in the question? Ian't that the whole point of comments?

Comment: Did you get homes safely ???

Comment: @MartinF The OP has not returned to this site since posting the question. Many follow up questions has been asked of the OP in the comments and most of those have been either moved to chat or deleted by admins on this site. At this time we probably shouldn't expect the OP to return to respond to any of the follow up questions.

Comment: @kasperd because there's about a 95% chance this question was not real. There's a lot of red flags and I've been waiting for someone to call it out but nobody has (or their comments were deleted).

Comment: @Marc.2377 - I'm as intrigued as hell about the 'case of fake CV'. Streisand effect, anyone?

Comment: @MartinF it was giving rise to a great deal of side-discussion in the comments. It's also arguably not all that relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @Richard just refer to the chat room link by Jane S and also be sure to read all answers.

Comment: @Mark Henderson : You know, as I visited and revisited this thread a few times to follow the intrigue, I slowly also started to think I caught the faintest whiff of a hoax... I dunno, it just didn't quite seem to pass the smell test no more...

Comment: @kasperd Hey, it's only been two weeks.  Maybe the OP is still on the bus home.

Comment: @user1602 It has not been two weeks anymore, and OP still hasn't answered

Comment: Legend says that OP is still at the airport to this day.

Comment: Two years later, 1) what happened in the end? Enquiring minds want to know. 2)  why have you not accepted an answer?

Comment: Almost 3 years later... time to mobilize a search-and-rescue operation.

Answer (score 505):

> Seriously, what the heck? Is this normal for an employer to do?

No, this is *completely* unacceptable. Sure, the interview didn't work out, but screwing the candidate because of that is just so, so bad.

> Do I have any recourse against this employer?

As a legal question which is going to depend on your jurisdiction and that of the employer. You'd need to talk to an actual lawyer.

As others have commented, independent of the legal aspect, "naming and shaming" is an option. I would very rarely advocate that behaviour, but in this case I think it's worth making other candidates aware of the risk they take interviewing with this company. However:

1. Make at least a nominal attempt to reconcile things with the company first.
2. Stack Exchange is not the platform on which to name and shame.

> The more I think about, the more I'm thinking I must have said something offensive to somebody in an interview. Is there any way to ask them what I said (so that I can avoid this mistake in the future)?

You can ask, at which point there are two possibilities:

1. This was actually a mistake and/or more sensible heads have prevailed at the company, in which case I'd hope they'd refund your expenses and the like.
2. They seriously meant to do this, in which case I doubt they'll answer.

I honestly cannot think of anything which would cause me to act in this way towards a candidate; there's plenty you could say which would cause me to terminate the interview on the spot and walk you out the door, but I'm not going to screw someone in a way which would reflect so negatively on the company for any future candidates.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88488/discussion-on-answer-by-philip-kendall-potential-employer-flew-me-out-for-interv).

Comment: I agree that this isn’t the place to name and shame, but don’t think that just including the name in the question or in a comment would be naming and shaming.  I think the name and location should have been in the question.

Comment: I wouldn't go out of my way to cause harm to said company, but I definitely would want to know it's name and tell everyone I know not to apply to their jobs, ever.  This type of action is not simply an overreaction of one person, but something very systemic to the company.  It's a gigantic red flag IMO.

Comment: Name and shame might not have an impact in this case anyway as company which is doing these kind of acts are unlikely to feel easily ashamed

Comment: @senseiwu It's not for their benefit, it's for the benefit of anyone else who might be thinking of interviewing there.

Comment: In regards to the "naming and shaming" throwing your experience on the Glassdoor page of that company and branch will ensure that people know the truth.

Answer (score 279):

Be sure to post to [GlassDoor, etc](https://blog.ongig.com/employer-branding/the-top-5-sites-for-employer-reviews-ratings), but be absolutely sure to post only the exact truth, with nothing opinion based which could get you sued.

Do that - after you have found a lawyer; most will give a free consultation if they are fairly sure of a win, for which you probably have grounds (especially give that "had to eat scraps from other customers").

If you want to know more about the legal side of things, you can look at the cross-posted question on our [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/36259/if-a-company-agrees-to-pay-travel-cost-for-a-job-interview-is-the-promise-bindi).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88382/discussion-on-answer-by-mawg-potential-employer-flew-me-out-for-interview-cance).

Comment: "(especially give that "had to eat scraps from other customers")" I don't think that particular part changes anything regarding winning or losing a lawsuit. Either op is entitled to compensation or not. If op is not, it's their problem they were stranded, it doesn't suddenly become the employers. (Just to be clear, in my opinion they have grounds for a suit).

Comment: I just thought that that could be classified as pain & suffering,  or whatever it is the TV lawyers use to get millions. The company, albeit indirectly, humiliated the OP (but I also suggest that a lawyer could make a case for kidnap or false imprisonment :-)

Comment: I am very sorry to say, that, no attorney in the US will take this case.  Unless it's a very, very big brand-name company where an attorney smells blood on a whacky situation.

Comment: Isn't opinion exempt from libel/slander laws? What gets you in trouble is incorrect statements of fact.

Comment: @Mawg I'm also no lawyer, but I don't see any case for kidnapping or false imprisonment here at all. The company simply isn't restricting OP's personal movement - they're just not paying for it.

Comment: @Anyon I agree with you, though it seems that there is growing acceptance of the reasoning that if the only accessible personal movement requires financial means you do not have, then you don't actually have freedom of movement, and if someone *knowingly* causes that condition, then you don't have that freedom of movement *because* of that someone. I wouldn't expect this argument to win in court any time soon, but I find myself thinking that we'll be seeing things turning that way in some jurisdictions within a couple of decades.

Comment: @Anyon (cont) that said, even if the above hypothetical development progressed, I don't see that OP could prove that he was really fully helplessly stranded in such a way (because he did have other options, arguably less accessible, but not inaccessible), or that the prospective employer knew he would be thus trapped (because unless he told them about his rather strained financial situation, and unless they didn't have good reasons to suspect his claim, I'm not sure you could say the result was intentional on their part).

Comment: The exact truth can't get you sued? News to me.

Comment: @anyon: They aren't restricting OP's personal movement (which would be criminal), but he did make a good faith reliance on the plane ticket offered to him in exchange for coming to the interview, and their cancellation of that ticket is a tort and they can be held responsible for *all* financial losses that directly result from their action, including not only alternative transportation but also lodging and meals while waiting for that transportation.  Reimbursement for pain and suffering is a bit more of a stretch but probably worth trying for.

Comment: @BenVoigt Indeed, and those losses may also include loss of income in this case. However, my comment was not an attempt at assessing the full situation, just a response to one of Mawg's comments above.

Comment: @mtraceur I agree that someone could make that argument, and that making it stick is the tricky part. It'd probably work in some cases - say if you're flown out to an oil rig or remote island - but that was evidently not the case here, as the Greyhound bus was an option.

Comment: @JAD That's not a coincidence.  Much earlier in the initial comments the legal side of things were brought up and another member cross-posted to the law SE.  It is explicitly mentioned in the question by a later edit.  You don't really need to mention it...

Comment: @Nelson I'm not sure why you think I thought it was a coincidence. At the time there was no mention of the specific question, so there was a point in mentioning it, thank you very much.

Comment: I had one similar case where I was flown in and kept in a room with no food and barely anything to drink for 6 hours, going through 1 tech test and 5 rounds of interviews, the last one with the head manager of the department looking to hire me.

Because I was jet lagged (coast to coast), tired and with low sugar level, I had issues answering her questions, which were the same I had been asked 4 times before during the day.

I was then kicked out very rudely, and I mean very. They never answered my requests for a feedback or even a formal nay. They did pay my flight and expenses.

Answer (score 115):

> Seriously, what the heck? Is this normal for an employer to do?

No. As far as slimy tactics by employers go, this is pretty up there. If I were you I'd name & shame them on glassdoor and the like. If they're in any sort of public spotlight the PR from that will be disastrous. Nobody wants to interview much less work for a company with that track record.

> Do I have any recourse against this employer?

Thats a question for a lawyer specializing in employment law. Try to find one that offers free consultations.

> The more I think about, the more I'm thinking I must have said
>   something offensive to somebody in an interview. Is there any way to
>   ask them what I said (so that I can avoid this mistake in the future)?

Even if you did, I have never heard of a employer doing this, and I'm pretty sure almost nobody actually does this. If you are an employer flying people out for interviews, you CAN NOT afford the bad publicity such a stunt will give you. Imagine what happens if a company like that invites me to an interview and I read THAT on a review site? Hard pass just on precaution.

Comment: If I were applying for a position, the potential employer offered to fly me out, and I found this type of information on Glassdoor or another site, I'd email the recruiting manager, send him the link and politely decline with an indication that no matter how nice the town is, I've no desire to be stuck there if the interview doesn't go well.

Answer (score 92):

> Is this normal for an employer to do?

I've swapped 'horror interview' stories with other developers and managers, but I've never heard of this happening.

> I must have said something offensive

Maybe, but only blame yourself for blowing the interview.
Don't blame yourself for the return plane ticket fiasco.

This is likely a single person making a big mistake.
The ones that covered for that mistake afterwards (I assume you talked to multiple people there) also seem culpable to me at this point, but IANAL<sup>1</sup>.

If you made offensive remarks during the interview I would want you not just out of my face, but also out of my town. I would abruptly (but politely) end the interview - *it wouldn't occur to me* to cancel your return flight.

If you totally lied about your experience, I might recommend to my company that we ask you to compensate us for the plane ticket and hotel. But I don't expect most companies ever would pursue it because of the bad PR that could come from it.

---

<sup>1</sup> IANAL = I Am Not A Lawyer = I believe this is true, but it isn't a legal opinion.

Comment: "it wouldn't occur to me to cancel your return flight." This can't be emphasized enough.

Comment: I also can't imagine the company getting anything close to full amount for canceling hours before the flight.  Most airlines give you nothing for doing this.  I couldn't find hard numbers on this though.

Answer (score 73):

What the company did was in extremely poor taste, so much so, that I wonder if there might be something more happening, especially since you said you bombed the interview, both technically and personally.

In your job application, were you truthful and honest?
Did you lie or seriously exaggerate about your skills, experience or history?
Was there a phone screen before the interview trip? Why did the phone screen go well enough to merit an interview then the interview went so poorly?

Basically, if you were not the job applicant you said you are: If you lied on your resume, or had someone coach you through a phone screen, and then were discovered in the interview, I think the company would have a real right to be extremely pissed off, and possible a legal right due to fraud to claw back some of their expenditures.

If you are confident everything on your end was honest and level, and you just had a really bad interview for a job that was a poor fit, then you probably have a strong legal case and the ability to create a PR and Recruiting Nightmare for the company.

**PS**
If you do decide to make it a Public Relations / Recruiting Situation, you might consider making it about the individuals involved as well as the Company.   Companies can be faceless, nameless, bureaucratic beasts, but if you name the HR-recruiter and Hiring Manager involved, and make them responsible for their own decisions, it might be more effective.   Check with a lawyer and be careful to avoid unjust defamation.

**Edit**
After awhile, another possibility that occurred to me is that this might be an effective way for someone from the company to embezzle money:.  They look for candidates who have bombed, then cancel the return ticket, routing the refund to their own account rather than the company.   The company wouldn't know that the candidate was left stranded, and whoever re-routed the money would have pocketed the cost of a refundable ticket!

If you have only spoken to one person at the company so far, who kept repeating the same "other direction" line over and over, they may be the embezzler, hoping you will just go away.   You need to speak to at least a second person at the company, and get an acknowledgement that the company really did cancel your ticket.  Otherwise, this may be part of a much more serious crime.

Comment: when you fly out a candidate, all the money is gone in one atomic transaction.  it's never coming back or half back.  even if the candidate lies/cheats/etc

Comment: @sudorm-rfslash What do you mean? In this case the company did get some money back. "The agent told me that my ticket was cancelled by the buyer for a partial refund."

Comment: I should have added "from a sane manager's perspective"... yes of course IRL you can get the money back but you should think of it as inaccessible

Comment: even if the company ended the interview believing that they had been defrauded by the candidate, there is a proper recourse through the court system to reclaim their expenses. Vigilante justice certainly is **not** a justifiable response.

Comment: Note that the people at the company are people, too. They may have come to a conclusion after the OP left that *they* had been screwed over, and cancelled the return ticket as a knee-jerk reaction. The size of the company was not specified, nor the level of the position. I'm not arguing this is a *good* thing, by any means....

Comment: Hmm... I kind of doubt the embezzlement theory. Any refund would normally be issued only to the original form of payment, so unless the employee somehow put the flight on his personal card in the first place, it seems like the refund would just go right back onto the corporate card.

Comment: @Tom, the aspect of "vigilante justice" (or lack thereof) is discussed in the [answer on Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/36261/6902).

Comment: @DavidMulder I laugh at the idea that you can get a refund of any useful amount by cancelling **hours** before the flight.  Most companies explicitly state minimum 24 hrs for something ridiculous like 10% or less.  The rest simply gives you nothing.  It's really hard to find hard numbers because I don't think they want to give to anything back TBH.  Stranding a potential candidate 3 days in an airport for a price of a simple steak dinner is just nasty work.

Comment: @Nelson:  Most airlines specifically offer Refundable Tickets:  They cost considerably more up-front, but are ***fully*** refundable up until the moment the flight is closed.   If this ticket was in fact in the Refundable category, it could indicate pre-meditation on the employer's part to cancel the ticket.  See:  https://heelsfirsttravel.boardingarea.com/2015/08/24/cancellation-fees-when-to-buy-refundable-airline-tickets/

Answer (score 22):

In fact, as HR should be booking the flights, but HR would not be conducting the interview, someone has **gone out of their way** to cancel that flight.
It may even be that the "sponsor" has been fired and had their approval rights revoked.

After all if they could not screen you out, their own bona fides are then highly suspect.

This is actually quite hard to do and would have left a wide trail. That they used refundable tickets is significant.

You bombed at the interview, was the position misrepresented or in any way "Bait and Switch"? Sometimes the copy for the job is garbage.

Otherwise I would invoice for time and expense, and then sue for liquidated damages.

OP should consult with a lawyer first, they are very good at this kind of billing.

Comment: There exist good reasons to use refundable tickets: candidates might cancel on short notice.

Comment: Was it pointed out somewhere that HR booked the flight? If so I missed that.

Comment: @DavidZ, no but typically in large companies HR sets up the interviews. Technical interviewers would certainly have better things to do with their time than book flights and hotels.

Comment: @gerrit The full refund has a window of activation.  I have yet to find an airline that gives me full refund for cancelling **hours** before the flight.

Comment: @Nelson: that depends on the ticket you buy. Really refundable tickets can usually be cancelled even after check-in.

Comment: @gerrit But refundable tickets are massively, massively more expensive than non-refundable ones. You'd need to have a huge proportion of your candidates cancelling for it to be worthwhile buying refundable tickets.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That, or an employer with a habit of rescheduling interviews on short notice.

Answer (score 11):

The only reasonable situation where this would be a valid reaction to, would be if you lied on your CV in an important point.

I am not mentioning a little exaggeration, not something like blowing all technical questions where you did not have as much experience as one would like, but misstating hard facts, like making up a PHD. Something like that would be fraud, and an employee would be obligated, should he become aware of such a situation to limit the damage to his employer.

Nonetheless, the behavior they showed is unprofessional - it should be clearly stated if that happens.

In all other cases, the behavior is completely unusual, unprofessional, and should be reason for consulting a lawyer.

Comment: I think even if (totally hypothetically, not saying this is the case) OP committed fraud by totally lying on their CV, canceling the ticket without informing OP, thus leaving OP stranded at the airport, is not a "valid reaction", and more than just unprofessional. If the company believed OP had committed fraud against them, they could have kept the ticket active, and then asked OP to pay back the travel costs. If OP refused, legal action would have been the most professional and acceptable play by the company, however, PR-wise, even that would probably not have been such a good idea.

Comment: I agree with that. Even if OP blew all technical questions on a topic he claimed to be an expert in, I don't think this would justify canceling the ticket. Performance during interviews is not just about skills/ knowledge, it's also about the psychological and physical state the candidate is in for example. The only exception which would justify canceling the ticket is a "hard" lie, something which was obviously a deliberate attempt to mislead the company on a very important matter.

Comment: Sadly, this is the only answer which matches all of the facts -- the OP stated they blew the technical questions and the interviewers didn't like them. I've interviewed candidates where I was fairly certain the candidate had stretched their experience, and things usually get very tense as the interview wore on. In one instance the misrepresentations were so obvious we wanted to know who the real person was so we could hire them. I would never suggest revoking a return flight for any other reason, but if fraud were obvious, I'd be open to it.

Comment: Being realistic it's unlikely that they'd want to pursue a legal option of getting their money back. It would be a troublesome and potentially expensive way of recovering a relatively small amount, considering they're dealing with someone they'll never see again living (probably) a few states away or in another country, and they probably never stated honesty as a condition for paying the air fare. That's not to defend what they did of course... But it sounds more like the action of a spiteful and pissed-off boss than a HR person who saw it as a valid legal move.

Comment: It's hard to imagine that they could have detected a false CV during an interview.  I've interviewed candidates with pre-checked CV's who just did really badly - because they froze on the interview, or they just weren't that good and had softball jobs.  You can't really tell a bad candidate or a candidate having a bad day from a fake candidate just by talking to them...

Comment: @TomSwirly - Yep, I've definitely experienced a "bad day" before - did an interview, froze up completely (even though it was stuff I've done a million times before and find pretty easy - it was parsing a CSV file) and didn't get the job.

Comment: I am not sure why this answer is so controversial. I understand that it's not well liked, but currently it is at 16+ and 8- votes......

Comment: I did not downvote this answer. But, I disagree with what you said that the **only** reasonable explanation is lying on the cv. The OP did say "_I must have said something offensive to somebody in an interview._".  To me it is also possible that the OP might have said something offending the interviewer, e.g. some racial remarks, some sexual biased comments, or possibly some profanity words. Any of these could incur some extreme actions. Some people are very narrow-minded.

Comment: @scaaahu: That is not what I stated.

Comment: -1 this answer by a non-lawyer states confidently that canceling a flight is a "valid reaction" if there was resume fraud, despite the lawyers on Law SE stating that it is not in fact a legally justifiable reaction.

Comment: "_The only reasonable sitation that this would be a valid reaction to would be if you lied on your CV in an important point_" is in the Version 1 of your answer. My point is that "The only reasonable". In particular, that "**only**". Are you claiming someone else used your account? If so, you need to report it.

Comment: No, i am claiming that "reasonable situation this would be a valid reaction to" is different from "reasonable explanation" (for the behavior). Other Answers gave examples where i would say "a reasonable explanation for the incident", but not an valid reaction from the company (like invitation was given by somebody without the authority or the company in severe difficulties). All of these are situations which are unreasonably caused on the side of the company, but may be possible and believable causes for the behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Document document document.  Get your facts in writing.  Call the airline for ticket records.  Document the additional expenses. File a complaint with the attorney general of your state and the one of the employer.

Wait for a response and then consider legal action.   Write your congressperson as well. Seek out free resources first. Perhaps a well written letter from a state or federal official will get you reimbursed.

First document.  Then organize.  Then seek assistance in writing a letter to one of the officials noted.

This is unacceptable.    Shame them at a last resort.  Take the high road while you seek assistance.

Once you get restitution or reach a dead end then sue them or drag them through the mud until you are satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

This is completely unacceptable. Do talk to them to see if they can make this right.

Assuming they don't, if you still want your revenge, I would suggest contacting the press - try somewhere like buzzfeed, huffington post, or the daily mail. If this story gets carried on somewhere high traffic, it will come up whenever anyone googles the company. You won't get your money back (it will not be worth the money to get legal recourse, I suspect) but you will have had your revenge.

And speaking of revenge, take the time to cool off and consider the maxim that when you go seeking revenge, first you should dig two graves.

Comment: This answer seems to be advocating going for "revenge", while also citing an old Chinese proverb that warns of the dangers and pitfalls of revenge?

Comment: Well, there's no meaningful compensation here, because it's going to be costly to pursue. The recourse is only revenge to expose this behaviour - but revenge has its own dangers.

Comment: "Do talk to them to see if they can make this right." OP already tried that and was told to stop harassing them.  I would also highlight that in cases like this, OP *MAY* be awarded their legal fees also

Comment: @UKMonkey Vanishingly unlikely in the US.

Comment: @Marcin: On the other hand the US treble damages may well be enough to afford the attorney.

Comment: @Joshua Under what statute? You don't just get treble damages because someone has been very bad.

Comment: @Marcin: Fraud.

Comment: @Joshua Fraud is not a statute, it's a concept. Also...what's the fraud here?

Answer (score -12):

The more popular answers have suggested something along the lines of attempting to recover your losses through legal means. I would suggest that may be a bad idea, as might be something like "naming and shaming". I'll explain at the end.

I've conducted a fair number of interviews over the last 20+ years and the #1 cause of a candidate completely bombing an interview is substantial misstatements of experience, either willfully, or because the position wasn't understood. A good interviewer will try and ease any stress during an interview which might be making things go poorly, but if all of the efforts at putting a candidate at ease fail, resume-padding -- willful or accidental (not understanding the position) -- is usually the most likely cause.

I've had "bombing" candidates go two ways -- they either realize they are a complete mis-match and end the interview (or acknowledge the fact at the end), or they get defensive. In one instance, the candidate apparently told their recruiter we'd accused them of lying (we hadn't -- we discussed it among ourselves afterwards, but no one had implied that during the interview) and the recruiter contacted us. We explained how badly the interview went, and that was that.

I don't know where you are in your career, because you didn't say, but I'm going to share an observation. Quite often early career people assume they can stretch experience because they feel they are ready for an advancement. What they don't understand is how interviewers are often selected. I've been a software engineer for pushing 40 years. I've done a lot of different things, so I've been picked to interview people at 4 of my last 5 gigs. I interview people for competence in their claimed areas of experience. It usually takes me 5 minutes or less to determine if they have the experience they claim. If things are going badly, I have techniques for putting candidates at ease and trying to improve how things are going to determine where their experience lies.

I'm truly sorry you had this experience, because it sounds absolutely miserable. That said, if I had a candidate who completely bombed, word would get back to HR or the hiring manager immediately.

The best reason to chalk this up to a learning experience has to do with the nature of lawsuits. The admitted fact that you bombed the interview will not go well at trial. I'm not a lawyer, but I suspect you'd have to explain how you both bombed the interview and didn't significantly misstate your qualifications. You didn't say they asked you off-topic or irrelevant questions ("I was asked front-end questions, and I'm a back-end developer interviewing for a back-end position", for example). More to the point, if it were determined at trial that you misstated your qualifications, that would manage to follow you around. Attempting to "name and shame" an employer can also go badly. Again, you'd have to explain how you bombed an interview and it's somehow their fault.

My suggestion is to take a long and hard look at the questions you were asked and why you did so poorly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88674/discussion-on-answer-by-julie-in-austin-potential-employer-flew-me-out-for-inter).